# How to work with cookie and redirect in codeigniter4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Hellow everyone. I'm working with codeigniter4 where I want to be able to store cookie and then redirect to another page. If I set a cookie without including redirection process, Cookie stores successfully, But the issue is when I do redirection, the cookie did't saved anymore.
How can I solve and make cookie saved and redirect.

```
public function loginProcessor()
{
    helper(['cookie']);
    $checkStatus = true;

    if ($checkStatus) 
    {
        set_cookie('nameCookie', 'CookieSomething', time() + 60*60*24*30);
    }

    return redirect()->to('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: I believe there is an issue with the set_cookie function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778869/codeigniter-4-set-cookie-not-setting) - I have used my own instead.

Comment: I have tried so much but not succeed. How to solve this?

Comment: I saw now you have asked same issue, How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth saying I've also had problems with the Session library which uses the Cookie functions so have resorted to an older version which did work.

```
function setMyCookie($name,$value,$time,$params = array()){
    if (empty($params)){
        $config = config('App');

        $params = array(
            'expires'   => $time,
            'path'      => $config->cookiePath,
            'domain'    => $config->cookieDomain,
            'secure'    => $config->cookieSecure,
            'httponly'  => $config->cookieHTTPOnly,
            'samesite'  => $config->cookieSameSite,
        );
    }

    setcookie($name,$value,$params);
}
```

This is saved as a helper and then called from the controllers etc.

Comment: Thank you! It now work after changing to php setcookie function.

Answer (score 1):

If you append `->withCookies()` to the redirect then it will copy all cookies from the global response instance. For your example it would be:

```
public function loginProcessor()
{
    helper(['cookie']);
    $checkStatus = true;

    if ($checkStatus) 
    {
        set_cookie('nameCookie', 'CookieSomething', time() + 60*60*24*30);
    }

    return redirect()->to('dashboard')->withCookies();
}
```

[Source](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=redirect#redirect)